# Disable Link Onclick

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reddit-Style Voting Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975042/reddit-style-voting-button)

So I have been working on this site, an I wanted to create a stackoverflow/reddit style voting system into my site. I want to disable a link when user clicks on it so they won't be able to vote twice. Here is the code I have:

```
<a href="#" title="upvote" class="arrows" onclick ="submitVote(<?php echo
$lulz['link_id']; ?>, 1);
return false;">&uarr;</a>
```

I need to keep the current on-click function so I can add in the vote. I it is possible to add another to disable it (with cookies).

Comment: There already a working copy for this question. Please refer to [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975042/reddit-style-voting-button)

Answer (score 1):

People can cheat if you use cookies. Anyone can delete the cookie, so they'll be able to vote as many times as they're willing to delete their cookie. It's better to store the info on the server in addition to setting the cookie. But if security isn't that important and you want to use a cookie, just set the cookie at the end of submitVote(). At the beginning of submitVote(), you look for the cookie first. If it exists, then you don't send the vote to the server. You can use alert() to tell the user they can't vote twice. If it doesn't exist, then just submit the vote to the server and you add the cookie after.

Comment: I'm not sure how the code would work for this.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you do client–side can be defeated, you must check for multiple votes at the server. But you can do a partial implementation by simply removing the listener when they click the button:

```
<a href="voteManually.html" onclick="submitVote();  this.onclick='';">vote</a>
```

Note that simply re-loading the page will reinvigorate the listener, and deleting cookies will defeat a cookie solution, and resetting the modem will defeat IP sniffing, and…